# Getting strange http response codes, but the site is actually working

Tags: http, http-headers

When I view the URL below or the other below in the code it's displayed fine. I don't see anything unusual in the network tab when I press F12 in the browser, but with the code below I will get response codes 403 or 400. When I use the response code checker here http://httpstatus.io/ it will come back fine with a 200 response for both URLS.

I get a 403 for http://psychsignal.com/ using my code below.

```
URL u = new URL("http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/"); //returns 400 response code
//u.toURI();  //to check the syntax
HttpURLConnection huc =  (HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();
huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
//huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
huc.connect(); 
System.out.println(huc.getResponseCode());
```

Thanks if anyone has any ideas! This is actually my first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there's some restrictions placed on the User-Agent of the client. Some testing seems to support my theory:

If I use the curl default user agent:

```
# curl -I -H "User-Agent: curl/7.35.0" "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Connection: close
```

If I use a hacked up standard browser agent string:

```
# curl -I -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0" -0 "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 15:06:22 GMT
Connection: close
```

And then if I use a Java agent string (which is my guess as to what you're using):

```
# curl -I -H "User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_26" "http://www.nasdaqomxnordic.com/"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Connection: close
```

Only the "browser" user agent gets through. I'd try tweaking your code to set the [user agent string to something commonly found in a web browser](http://useragentstring.com/).

Comment: Same results for me, looks like the site is actively blocking some user agents.

Comment: Thanks guys! That makes sense.